# Error while run the powershell command

Tags: java, powershell, process, runtime.exec, ioexception

How to invoke the powershell command using java.

```
  try {
        ExecuteWatchdog watchdog = new ExecuteWatchdog(20000);
        Process powerShellProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                "powershell.exe \"D:\\testscript.ps1\"");
        if (watchdog != null) {
            watchdog.start(powerShellProcess);
        }
        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                powerShellProcess.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        System.out.println("Output :");
        while ((line = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

note : i map the correct path.

I tried with the above code but it gives the error like

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "powershell.exe": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:459)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:593)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:431)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:328)
    at com.powershell.PsJava.main(PsJava.java:17))
```

Anyone could you please help on this.

Comment: 1) Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  That might solve the problem.  If not, it should provide more information as to the reason it failed.  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for arguments which themselves contain spaces. 2) There is no need to add the major tag in the title.

Comment: it just cant find the file. Change `"powershell.exe"` to `"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"`

Comment: Thank u @Cole9350, Problem is resolved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Environment Variables are not always exposed to the java compiler. Your stack error is just telling you it cannot find the powershell executable, because it doesn't automatically know to look in the $PSHOME var.

The fix is just to specify the full path:
Change `"powershell.exe"` to `"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"`

Comment: can you please specify, change it where, should we add this as new path

Answer (score 0):

You can run the PowerShell command using the `ProcessBuilder` from Java.

```
ProcessBuilder builder =
    new ProcessBuilder("powershell.exe", "/c", "Get-Process");
Process p = builder.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

If the powershell executable *IS* in your path then make sure that you have not accidentally have `Use secret text(s) or file(s)` selected with **specific username password credentials** in the `Build Environment` section. I'm not sure why but this seemed to cause this issue when building on our slave!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we need to configure that the environment variable for `Powershell.exe` is in the path `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0` and then restart the system.

After, that, execute the PowerShell command or script.

Answer (score 0):

**I test all answers above and didnot worked !**
try this one ...
I have this problem and it was so so suffering :)) I can solve this problem in this way: first I add C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0 to my System path in environment variables in windows 10, after that I restart my Pc, after restarting I create a new scala sbt project but I choose scala version 11.10 and sbt version 0.0.3x instead of 1.x.x and It worked , wish you best !